# How to make a web page expire when the user leaves

Tags: javascript, php, internet-explorer, asp-classic

Is there a standard or proper way to make a web page expire? I do not want the user to be able to go back to a previous page. I am currently trying this.

```
<?php

header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
?>
```

Which works fine in IE 10 but in IE 11 it doesn't work. Is there a different way of doing this in IE 11? I have also tried using META tags they do not work in IE 11 either.

Comment: Setting the headers doesn't disable the back button. It makes IE have to retrieve the page again from the server rather than read it from the cache.

Comment: Yes I understand what it does.

Comment: With a standard page, there is no absolutely solid way of preventing the user seeing it again, since they already have it in their browser memory. However, if you are willing to require JavaScript, you could render the content on access-controlled pages via AJAX POST, which will not be cached. New visits to the page will therefore force a request, which can be denied depending on your requirements.

Comment: are you able to provide a link to some resources so i can learn more about this maybe an example or something?

Answer (score 0):

As long as a form submits, when it submits and you are redirected elsewhere, pressing back will bring up the standard browser alert saying you will have to resend data.

Comment: Right but they would still be able to get to that page. I would like to make the page expire so they cant access it anymore once they leave.

Comment: You can cause the page that processes the submitted form to not be included in the history by redirecting on the serverside. But you can't remove the form page from the history.